# Access count of message received?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Is it possible to access in a test how many times an object has received a certain message? My goal is to test that a class has received two class method calls the same number of times.

Logically, it seems like this count would be stored somewhere as code is executed.

This would look something like

```
allow(SomeClass).to receive(:method_1).at_least(1).times
allow(SomeClass).to receive(:method_2).at_least(1).times

# setup and code here

expect(method_1_received_times).to eq (method_2_received_times)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very pretty, but your could set up your own counters like this:

```
@method_1_received_count = 0
@method_2_received_count = 0
allow(SomeClass).to receive(:method_1) { @method_1_received_count += 1 }
allow(SomeClass).to receive(:method_2) { @method_2_received_count += 1 }

# setup and code here

expect(@method_1_received_count).to eq(@method_2_received_count)
```

Comment: Cool thanks, I didn't realize you could pass a block to allow/receive.